# jQuery toggle div backgrounds from data variables

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following div layer. Is there a way using maybe the jQuery click function to change the background-color to a certain color depending on how many clicks are made?

And also since there will be a unique id to the div layers too, maybe puting the value of the number of clicks/index number into the div where it currently says Click Count?

```
    .box {
        width:44px;
        height:44px;
        line-height:44px;
        border:1px solid #808080;
        border-radius:8px;
        text-align:center;
        color:#000;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:24px; 
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        cursor:context-menu;
    }


<div class="box" id="1001" style="background-color:#f4e8e8;" data-colors="#f4e8e8,#ed5151,#e0e554,#3ed179,#227ce3" data-index="0">
Click Count
</div>
```

So if data-index was lets say 0 then the first click would change the colour of the div to #ed5151

If the data-index was already set to 1 then the first click colour would be #e0e554 and so on.

Any ideas how this can be achieved with jQuery?

Also, i forgot to mention, when it reaches the last index and color it needs to cycle back to 0 and the color representing 0

Many thanks

Comment: Will the colors be the same for all elements, for all indices?

Comment: If a user clicks 10 times then which color needs to be set ?

Comment: @Ali Khanusiya I forgot to mention, after the last colour it needs to cycle back to index 0 and the color representing index 0

Comment: @xpy Yes colours are just cycling through index numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As this got rejected as a peer review, I am extending @GOB's answer;*

You can also change the text to show the count/index inside the DIV with the following inside the click function;

```
$(".box").click(function(){
  $this = $(this);

  var colors = $this.attr("data-colors").split(",");
  var maxIndex = colors.length - 1;
  var index = parseInt($this.attr("data-index"));

  if (index == parseInt(maxIndex)) { 
    $this.attr("data-index", 0); 
  } else { 
    $this.attr("data-index", index + 1)
  }

  $this.css("background-color",colors[index]);
  $this.html(index);
});
```

The requiring 2 clicks you mentioned in a comment is because the default background colour is the same as first index.

Here is an up to date JS-Fiddle fully working to what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/cqjfcnqx/

**EDIT**
Second JSFiddle example that compares the current background to the next index to stop the 2-clicks needed for changing the colour.

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/cqjfcnqx/1/

Comment: JokerDan is there a way around the 2 click problem. because when i load the page depending on what the stored value is in a database. If it is 0 then the default background will be the first color and the index will be 0. If value is 1 then the default background will be the second colour and index will be 1 so that it continues from there.

Comment: @Ahmed Simply change the INDEX to start at (index + 1).
So you could have on the DIV element, `data-index="1"` instead of 0. Failing that you can have on page loading you increment the index with JQuery. You could also do a comparison of the current background colour and the next index colour, if they are the same you + 2 instead of + 1 to the index.

Comment: @Ahmed
As an extension to my previous comment, see this JSFiddle example which compares the index colour value to the current/default.
JSFiddle updated in the main answer too. : https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/cqjfcnqx/1/

Answer (score 3):

In a more CSS approach, you define your color rules by the `[data-index]` selector and you just change the index on click:

```js
$('.el').on('click', function() {

  var index = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
  index = index == 4 ? 0 : index + 1;
  $(this).attr('data-index', index);

});
```

```css
.el {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}
[data-index='0'] {
  background-color: #f4e8e8;
}
[data-index='1'] {
  background-color: #ed5151;
}
[data-index='2'] {
  background-color: #e0e554;
}
[data-index='3'] {
  background-color: #3ed179;
}
[data-index='4'] {
  background-color: #227ce3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el" data-index="0"></div>
<div class="el" data-index="0"></div>
<div class="el" data-index="0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".box").click(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  var colors = $this.attr("data-colors").split(",");
  var index = parseInt($this.attr("data-index"));
  if (index >= colors.length) index = 0;
  $this.attr("data-index",index+1);
  $this.html(index+1);
  $this.css("background-color",colors[index]);
});
```

I've made you a little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pha3vdt/3):

**Edit**
new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pha3vdt/7):

Comment: Thanks, 3 issues with the JSFiddle I can see. Firstly, when clicked it doesnt go to the next colour on the first click. It seems to require two clicks. Secondly the click counter display isnt changing. And lastly when it gets to the last index number and colour it should loop back to index 0 and the first color.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click", "div.box", function () {

    $this = $(this);
    var arrColors = $this.attr("data-colors").split(",");
    var intCurrentIndex = parseInt($this.data("index"));
    var intNewIndex = intCurrentIndex == arrColors.length - 1 ? 0 : intCurrentIndex + 1;
    $this.css("background-color", arrColors[intNewIndex])
            .data("index", intNewIndex)
            .text("Click Count : " + intNewIndex);

});
```

```css
.box
{

    line-height:44px;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    border-radius:8px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:context-menu;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="1001" style="background-color:#f4e8e8;" data-colors="#f4e8e8,#ed5151,#e0e554,#3ed179,#227ce3" data-index="0">
    Click Count : 0
</div>
<div class="box" id="1002" style="background-color:#f4e8e8;" data-colors="#f4e8e8,#ed5151,#e0e554,#3ed179,#227ce3" data-index="0">
    Click Count : 0
</div>
<div class="box" id="1003" style="background-color:#f4e8e8;" data-colors="#f4e8e8,#ed5151,#e0e554,#3ed179,#227ce3" data-index="0">
    Click Count : 0
</div>
<div class="box" id="1004" style="background-color:#f4e8e8;" data-colors="#f4e8e8,#ed5151,#e0e554,#3ed179,#227ce3" data-index="0">
    Click Count : 0
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.box').html('0');
$('.box').click(function(){
    var intIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
  var colors = $(this).attr('data-colors').split(',');

  if (intIndex >= colors.length) {
    intIndex = 0;
    $(this).attr('data-index', '0');
  }

  $(this).css('backgroundColor', colors[intIndex]);
  $(this).attr('data-index', intIndex + 1)

  $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html()) + 1)
});
});
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/9g333e8k/1/

Comment: It keeps the proper click count and rotates colors with each click